# Cygwin: Unable to initialize GTK: could not open display

Tags: cygwin, xserver

I've got a Win 10 box with Cygwin and the X packages installed. I run xlaunch and start up the X server. I then do "ssh -Y user@myserver". Then I su and run virt-manager. I get an error:

```
Cygwin: Unable to initialize GTK: could not open display
```

echo $DISPLAY shows:

```
localhost:10.0
```

I've tried changing it with EXPORT DISPLAY=localhost:0.0 with no luck.

I've googled and read all of the similar questions but none address my problem, as simple as I'm sure it is.

Comment: Are you aware of `-nolisten tcp` ?  https://sourceware.org/ml/cygwin-announce/2015-10/msg00111.html

Comment: You nailed it. I restarted the x server with -listen tcp as an option, told the Windows firewall to allow this behavior on my local network and it worked! If you create an answer with that info I'll mark it as the correct answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from xorg-server version 1.17 , the option `-nolisten tcp` is now the default, so the server only accepts local connections on a unix domain socket.

To allow connection by TCP you should use the option `-listen` that has been added to restore the previous behaviour.

As reported by the package maintainer:
https://sourceware.org/ml/cygwin-announce/2015-10/msg00111.html